# Disable MySQL startup in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, boot, mysql

I want to prevent MySQL from starting in Ubuntu 10.04

I have used

```
update-rc.d -f mysql remove
```

and confirmed that there is no link to the `/etc/inid.d/mysql` script from any of the rc?.d directories.

I also ran `sysv-rc-conf` and it shows me that MySQL is NOT being called as part of the `rc.d` scripts.

It is still starting on boot.  How do I disable it?

Comment: mysqld is running under the mysql user account

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Ubuntu 10.04 has abandoned SysV init script approach to booting the system.

This link explains - http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/7033/1/

To prevent mysql from starting on boot

- 1 go to the /etc/init directory
- 2. open the mysql.conf file
- 3. comment out the "start on" line near the top of the file, the "start on" might be spread across two lines, so comment out both

If you want to manually start mysql, use the following command -

```
  service mysql start
```

Comment: Link is 404. Use http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/7033/1/

Comment: The link is fixed, and the answer is correct.

Comment: Instead of modifying the original `.conf` file, better use [override files](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#override-files): `(as root)# echo "manual" >> /etc/init/mysql.override`

Answer (score 0):

run the command as follows:

```
root@user:~# gedit /etc/init/mysql.conf
```

then comment out the starting lines, I think there should be two, and you are all set!

Happy Linuxing to All!

Comment: /etc/init/ and /etc/init.d/ are NOT the same! I can't downvote this because I don't have the reputation, and I can't edit it because it's only a two-character change.

Comment: @alberge - I made the edit. Waiting on peer review.

Answer (score 0):

As @[nh2](https://superuser.com/users/150943/nh2) mentioned in his [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/138116/disable-mysql-startup-in-ubuntu-10-04#comment579332_139059) there's another — a way [more clear/flexible way](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#override-files) to disable(/enable) upstart's task: «…

> With Upstart 1.3, you can make use of an "override file" and the manual stanza to achieve the same result in a simpler manner:

```
# echo "manual" >> /etc/init/myjob.override
```

…»