# Boot up process in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, performance, boot

I am using ubuntu 10.04. When I had installed the OS it hardly took 20 secs to boot. Later on I started installing s/w like apache server, mysql server, bacula server, dictionary server, etc. And now the boot up process takes more that 120 secs. So I did shutdown these process at boot up using sysv-rc-conf command. There hasn't been a second's improvement in the the boot process. I don't want these processes to start at boot up. I would do it manually. All I want is a fast Boot process.

What has gone wrong. How do I speed up the boot process.

Comment: You could create a BootChart to see what's taking so long: http://www.bootchart.org/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is not just one place that lists all applications that start on bootup. 
You're doing the right thing by using sysv-rc-conf, but it won't help you with mysql and probably others.

Take a look at this question (that I asked) for details on the new upstart boot process.

[Disable MySQL startup in Ubuntu 10.04](https://superuser.com/questions/138116/disable-mysql-startup-in-ubuntu-10-04)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about ubuntu's boot process, but there's one thing very significant about the boot time- the way the services are started.

Usually most distributions start the processes one by one in the foreground. Therefore, the next command is not executed until the previous service's startup was successful/failure.

In Arch Linux, if you prepend the service name with an '@', like @mysql, then the process will start in background, i.e. it will just issue the startup command and move to next service, this way, the boot time is reduced a lot.

Check out if Ubuntu has some such feature, if yes, just start the most critical services, like D-Bus, HAL, Network in foreground and rest all in background.