# How does MySQL usually get started?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

I'm trying to ensure an app starts on boot up but after MySQL has been started. I can't however locate where MySQL is being started.

If I do a chkconfig, it says MySQL is off, yet I can readily access my databases with phpmyadmin.

If I look at my boot log, I can see it says MySQL Server is started, right after Apache2 is started.

In my rc5.d directory, I only see a symbolic link for Apache2 but nothing for MySQL. The startup script for MySQL appears in /etc/init.d.

rc.local has got nothing in it but comments.

So it appears to me like it's being run on startup, but not as a service. But I have next to no knowledge of Linux so don't put too much belief in that.

I would have originally installed MySQL via apt-get.

Where else can I look to find out where it is being started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at this link:

[Disable MySQL startup in Ubuntu 10.04](https://superuser.com/questions/138116/disable-mysql-startup-in-ubuntu-10-04)

Also after you disable it you can create your own startup script that will start MySQL and then start your application after it.

e.g.

```
#! /bin/bash
service mysql start
```

You will also need to `chmod +x` the startup script

Comment: The link on your link explained it perfectly. All is good.